# ImportError when starting Celery in daemon mode

Tags: python, celery, systemd, systemctl

My Celery works well in CLI mode:

- My project folder is organised this way: `jive/jive.py`
- jive.py file looks like:

  `app = Celery(include=['tasks.dummy_tasks','tasks.people_tasks',])`
  `app.config_from_object(CELERY_CONFIG_PATH)`
- I run a worker in CLI this way: `celery worker -A jive` and it works when I'm inside the `jive` folder.

Recently, I tried to [daemonize Celery using systemd](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#usage-systemd).

For this, 2 files are required. I will paste the important part only for both:

**/etc/celery/conf.d**

```
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
CELERY_BIN="/home/user1/venv/bin/celery"
CELERY_APP="jive"
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"
```

**/etc/systemd/system/celery.service**

```
[Service]
Type=forking
User=user1
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/celery/conf.d
WorkingDirectory=/home/user1
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
```

When running the service, it fails with the following errors after displaying status:

```
    (venv) [user1@localhost jive]$ systemctl status celery.service
    ● celery.service - Celery Service
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celery.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-03-07 14:59:56 CET; 2s ago
      Process: 16493 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c ${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES}    -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}    --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Mar 07 14:59:56 localhost.localdomain sh[16493]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Mar 07 14:59:56 localhost.localdomain sh[16493]: ImportError: No module named 'jive'
Mar 07 14:59:56 localhost.localdomain sh[16493]: celery multi v4.0.2 (latentcall)
```

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'` -> I suspect a PATH problem but not sure how to deal with this in a service. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your `WorkingDirectory` should probably be the directory containing the `jive` folder. So if `/opt/proj/jive/jive.py`, then your `WorkingDirectory` should probably be `/opt/proj`.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably a step in the right way, but now I get a `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'` instead.

Comment: This question is a variation of a systemd FAQ [Difference between systemd and terminal starting program](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239).

Comment: @MarkStosberg you're probably right. When running `systemctl show-environment` I got a `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`
which differs from `echo $PATH`-> `/home/user1/venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user1/.local/bin:/home/user1/bin` However I think I'm not supposed to set the systemctl PATH var manually.

Comment: @DavidD. - Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: @David, it's fine to set the `PATH` you need with `Environment=PATH=...` in your unit file.

Comment: @DirtyPenguin @MarkStosberg Actually it was just because the correct path is `/home/user1/jive` and not `/home/user1` .... I also removed the `user` part. Everything is ok now. No trouble with env var. Thanks guys for your help.